# Is there a way to do clustering in parallel using diana and parLapply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis

We have a very large numerical matrix that we wish to cluster using Diana, but it takes too long to do it. Is there any way to do it using parLapply? We have tried the following without success.

```r
dianaPAR = function(tMV_xAB) {
    diana_xAB = diana(tMV_xAB)
}

detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(11)
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(cluster)})

parlapply(cl, tMV_xAB, dianaPAR)


Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
11 nodes produced errors; first error: 'n' must be >= 2
```

Comment: Update code formatting, fix wording, add fitting tags

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to do this. I'm not even sure if it would be theoretically possible to parallelize hierarchical clustering approaches, but don't quote me on that.